# Не могу запустить rails s в production env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Работал над проектом в development environment, теперь пытаюсь запустить в production и выводит такое :

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.6 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:170:in `spec': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `establish_connection'
    from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
```

и в таком духе, мне нужно мигрировать базу данных ?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно мигрировать базу данных и указать `credentials` для новой базы в `config/database.yml`, в секции `production`.